# Python Dice gamble program

Tags: python

I have this dice program that rolls a pair of 6 sided die 3 times.
You start off with $500 in the bank and are asked to place a bet and pick a number between 2 and 12. If you guess the first roll you double your bet and add it to bank, 2nd roll you win 1 1/2 times your bet, 3rd roll you win your bet, otherwise your bet is subtracted from the bank. I just need help with calculations part I feel so dumb.

```
def main():
    bank = 500
    while bank > 0:
        print("You have $",bank,"in your account.")
        bet = int(input("Enter your bet =>"))
        guess = int(input("Choose a number between 2 and 12: "))
        print("Your guess is",guess)

        roll = 1 
        rolls = []
        while roll < 4:
            dice_pair = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6)
            rolls.append(dice_pair)
            print("Roll #",roll, "was",dice_pair)
            if dice_pair == rolls[0]:
                bank = bet * 2
            elif dice_pair == rolls[1]:
                bank = bet * 1.5
            elif dice_pair == rolls[2]:
                bank = bank + bet
            else:
                bank= bank - bet
            roll += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a list of rolls and doing comparisons like `dice_pair == rolls[0]` doesn't make sense: that's always going to be true on the first iteration. You're supposed to be checking `dice_pair == guess`, adjusting the bank based on the current value of `roll`, and perhaps ending the loop if the guess is correct (not quite sure about the rules there).

Comment: Also, for your first and second roll if statements, you forgot to add the value of the bank. So let's say I had $500 in the bank, I best $10 and guess 4, and I happen to get it right on the first roll. Your current code would result in my bank balance being only $20! You might want to consider using += and -= operators to make this easier.